# What is use of underScore in Double value in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I just recently look into Apple documentation I found code like below

```
extension Double {
    var km: Double { return self * 1_000.0 }
    var m: Double { return self }
    var cm: Double { return self / 100.0 }
    var mm: Double { return self / 1_000.0 }
    var ft: Double { return self / 3.28084 }
}
```

What is the use of "_" in double value? it's working without error why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a way to improve readability. According to [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID323):

> Numeric literals can contain extra formatting to make them easier to
>   read. Both integers and floats can be padded with extra zeros and can
>   contain underscores to help with readability. Neither type of
>   formatting affects the underlying value of the literal.

Comment: It would have been so nice if Apple could have added comments in their sample code.  Like "// '_' added for readability ".